# Angular mat-tabs to show all tab's content upon print

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-tab

Similar to the post here https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/44388, I need to update the print layout of a page. As I am using mat-tab for improving the layout from devices, I need to be able to print a report with all content. However, today only the content from the first tab is displayed. I would need the content to be displayed below each other. Example code:

```
<mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab label="First"> Content 1 </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Second"> Content 2 </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Third"> Content 3 </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

From device, only "Content 1" is displayed. From print layout, I would like it to be:

---

Content 1

Content 2

Content 3

---

I have tried to update with css "@media print" but figured out to solve it.

Anyone that has solved this before?

Thanks!